# Restkit 0.20rc1 - Mapping Entity without KVC

Tags: ios, json, mapping, restkit, key-value-observing

So i am trying to mapping a JSON object without KVC with Restkit 0.20

#### The JSON whithout KVC

```
{
    "created_at": "2013-03-11T22:13:05Z",
    "facebookId": "2343434322",
    "firstname": "testuser",
    "id": 197,
    "mail": "test@gmail.com",
    "name": "test",
    "phone": "098748394",
    "sex": null,
    "twitterId": null,
    "updated_at": "2013-03-11T22:13:05Z",
    "vehiculeDescription": "car",
    "recommendCount": 0
}
```

#### My app delegate

```
RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:WEBSERVICE]];

// Initialize managed object store
NSURL *modelURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]      pathForResource:@"KojoClient" ofType:@"momd"]];
// NOTE: Due to an iOS 5 bug, the managed object model returned is immutable.
NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel = [[[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL] mutableCopy];
RKManagedObjectStore *managedObjectStore = [[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedObjectModel];
manager.managedObjectStore = managedObjectStore;

RKEntityMapping *utilisateurMapping =
    [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:NSStringFromClass([Utilisateur class]) inManagedObjectStore:manager.managedObjectStore];
utilisateurMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"remoteid"];
[utilisateurMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
    @"remoteid": @"id",
    @"name": @"name",
    @"firstname": @"firstname",
    @"phone": @"phone",
    @"facebookid": @"facebookId",
    @"mail": @"mail",
    @"vehiculeDescription" : @"vehiculeDescription",
    @"recommendCount" : @"recommendCount",
    @"created_at": @"created_at",
    @"updated_at": @"updated_at",
    @"twitterId": @"twitterId"
 }];

/**
 Register our mappings with the provider
 */


RKResponseDescriptor* utilisateursDescriptor =
[RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:[utilisateurMapping inverseMapping]
                                        pathPattern:@"/utilisateurs"
                                            keyPath:@""
                                        statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

RKResponseDescriptor* utilisateurDescriptor =
    [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:[utilisateurMapping inverseMapping]
                                            pathPattern:@"/utilisateurs/:remoteid"
                                            keyPath:@""
                                            statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
RKResponseDescriptor* facebookUtilisateurDescriptor =
                                            [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:[utilisateurMapping inverseMapping]
                                            pathPattern:@"/face_utilisateurs/:facebookid"
                                            keyPath:@""
                                            statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

[manager addResponseDescriptorsFromArray:@[utilisateursDescriptor, utilisateurDescriptor, facebookUtilisateurDescriptor]];

// Serialize to JSON
manager.requestSerializationMIMEType=RKMIMETypeJSON;

/**
 Complete Core Data stack initialization
 */

[managedObjectStore createPersistentStoreCoordinator];

NSString *storePath = [RKApplicationDataDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Application.sqlite"];
NSError *error;

NSPersistentStore *persistentStore = [managedObjectStore addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath:storePath fromSeedDatabaseAtPath:nil  withConfiguration:nil options:@{NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption:@YES, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption:@YES} error:&error];

NSAssert(persistentStore, @"Failed to add persistent store with error: %@", error);

// Create the managed object contexts
[managedObjectStore createManagedObjectContexts];

// Configure a managed object cache to ensure we do not create duplicate objects
managedObjectStore.managedObjectCache = [[RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache alloc] initWithManagedObjectContext:managedObjectStore.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext];
```

The problem is when i want to get my objet with :

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:path parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {

                 if(![[mappingResult firstObject] isKindOfClass:[Utilisateur class]]) {
                     //Dont work
                 }

             } nil];
```

The RKMappingResult object has no class.

[Unknown class image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIQQW.png)

But the mapping work

> Printing description of mappingResult->_keyPathToMappedObjects:
>   {
>      "" =     {
>          "created_at" = "2013-03-11T22:13:05Z";
>          facebookid = 4567898765;
>          firstname = Test;
>          mail = "test@gmail.com";
>          name = TestName;
>          phone = 45678976587;
>          recommendCount = 0;
>          remoteid = 197;
>          "updated_at" = "2013-03-11T22:13:05Z";
>          vehiculeDescription = "test";
>      };
>   }

I don't understand why my object mapped has no class.

I have follow the [Object Mapping Tutorial without KVO](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping)

And can't change the server JSON style.

#### Update 1

I try without the NSStringFromClass, dont work.

Comment: I guess that `NSStringFromClass([Utilisateur class])` wouldn't work. Use the name of the class instead, e.g. `@"Utilisateur"`.

Comment: I try without too and it's dont work ...

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using `[utilisateurMapping inverseMapping]` for `RKResponseDescriptor` with `RKEntityMapping`? Maybe if you try:

```
RKResponseDescriptor* utilisateursDescriptor =
[RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:utilisateurMapping
                                        pathPattern:@"/utilisateurs"
                                            keyPath:@""
                                        statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
```